# Problem to find ALPS Encoder with only reference number

Tags: identification, encoder

My ultrasonic tank uses two ALPS encoders. The problem is that both are defective and I would like to replace them.

However, I have a lot of trouble finding the same ones. Please would any of you know the reference of these items? (please find photo attached)

[image: Encoder 931]

Thank you very much in advance for your reply.

Comment: Looks like the EC11J series. Is the defective bit the missing shaft?

Comment: Note that what you're looking for is the *part number*, not the reference number. A reference number, e.g. SW1, C23, or Q4, is the number printed on the PCB so the person assembling or troubleshooting the board knows what to call the part in the context of this specific board. The part number, e.g. 2N2222, LM7805, or 1N4007, is the number assigned to the specific part by the manufacturer, which can be used to identify and order the part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer!! (2 days to find it).

Here it is: ALPS reference RDC803001A (100.000 cycles) or RDC803101A (20.000 cycles)

Thank you!

[edit] : The link for the datasheet is here: https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/15/alps_alps-s-a0005263269-1-1733231.pdf

Comment: Congratulations on finding it. If you can edit the answer and add a link to a datasheet or similar, that would help future readers. || Since you have found the answer yourself, you can "accept" (green tick) your own answer in 2 days time (48 hours after you asked the question), if no-one else adds a better answer (in your judgement). Please do come back to accept an answer, in order to close the topic and prevent readers being nagged by the site to answer it, since you already have the answer :-) Thanks.